# Book: Moles that build a raft, Tree that digs deeper than its friends

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find a book I read when I was young, roughly 25 years ago. I read it in German, which might complicate things, since sadly I don't know whether German was its original language or whether it was new when I read it.

The book contained multiple stories. The main story featured moles that had to go on a journey; at one point they built a raft to travel on a river.

Another story featured a tree (a weeping willow) and its friends. In a period of drought, the willow dug deeper than its friends and found a reservoir of water, but none of its friends believed it; in fact, they bullied it until they died of the drought. Later, new seeds appear and the new trees actually believe the willow.

Comment: You're off to a great start, but we could use some more details, such as when you read it and when you think it was published. What the cover may have looked like, and whether German was it's original language. Take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to get a nice list of checkpoints which may help you to remember more details. Also is there anything here that makes it particularly Fantastical? We normally don't consider anthropomorphic animals to be Fantasy.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'll read the guide and see if I remember any more details.
Unfortunately the only fantastical parts were the talking animals and talking trees, other than that, it was set in our world without sci-fi or fantasy elements. I figured I'd try asking it here, is there another stack exchange that's better suited for normal books?

Comment: You can ask on [literature.se] but they have their own guide (I haven't checked rigorously, but I'd be surprised if it wasn't almost identical) that you can find [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/779/280). They have a very high criteria for quality, being a small site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the book: it's called [Die drei kleinen Eulen und sieben andere Geschichten](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12206238-die-drei-kleinen-eulen-und-sieben-andere-geschichten) ("The Three Little Owls and seven other stories") by Erwin Moser.

It is actually a German book from 1989 - and yes, the title has nothing to do with the stories I remembered, but the chapter list shows that the stories are in there:

1. Die klugen Maulwürfe (← the smart moles)
2. Die Reise
3. Der Fuchs
4. König Luchs
5. Das Glühwürmchen und das Marienkäferchen
6. Der alte Iltis
7. Der Floh
8. Die Abenteuer einer Wolke
9. Die drei kleinen Eulen
10. Die glückliche Trauerweide (← the happy weeping willow)
11. Die Spitzmaus und der Pfirsichbaum

Comment: Congratulations!